# Devise: Where to put logic without overriding Registration Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

After a User is created via Devise I want various things to happen (e.g. an Account record to be created and its fields to be filled with various values, a fields within a Transaction table to be updated, etc.). I've tried "extending" Devise's Registration Controller

```
class MyRegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  prepend_view_path "app/views/devise"

  def create
     super
     # Generate your profile here
     @account = Account.new
     @account.user = current_user.id
  end  
end
```

However when I use this, devise stops redirecting, error checking, etc.  My next thought was to do the following in my User.model

```
after_create :build_user_account

def build_user_account
  @account = Account.new
  @account.user = current_user.id
end
```

But I've been reading that this code shouldn't be in the model AND I don't have access to current_user in the model.  I know this is amateurish stuff, but I'm stumped.  Should I do my own Authentication and rip Devise out or is there a way to code this correctly still using Devise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this business logic (each user object should have an Account) is suitable for the model.

You can use an observer to do this, or use the after_create callback like you did. Using the callback:

```
after_create :create_user_account

def create_user_account
  Account.create(:user_id => self.id)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your custom Registrations Controller you are calling super and then passing in your account creation logic. If I am not mistaken, the call to super tells it to only run the code in the Devise controller and ignores your code (I would have to go back through the controller code to make sure). I would try copying the method as is form the Devise controller, which you can find on [Github](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), and then passing in your logic. That should allow everything to work the way you want, and still have the appropriate redirects and validations.

If you do decide to do it outside of a custom Registrations Controller and put it in the model, you will have to use an `after_create` hook as @Jesse Wolgamott stated, so that you have access to the current_user method. While it may not be the "Rails way" to put business logic in the model, it is just sometimes unavoidable.

Answer (score -1):

Devise team recommends not using devise if you are a beginner ;-) That said, I think devise is stable and mature enough to be used, in place of a completely custom solution.

One thing, yes the current_user is not available in the model (I think). What I do is, in my controller:

```
  # POST /reports
  # POST /reports.json
  def create
    @report = Report.new(params[:report])
        @report[:user_id] = current_user[:id]
    @report[:name_seo] = @report[:name].to_slug
```

Although slightly off-topic, I found this article useful: http://www.communityguides.eu/articles/11